# Input.GetMouseButton(0) and RaycastHit2D hit are effecting multiple objects instead of just the one I'm clicking on

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onclick, touch

I'm trying to differentiate my clicks per each individual item but I can't seem to figure this out. I want to click and then have the item I'm clicking on rotate but all of the items rotate. Here's my code:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Ray ray = loadCam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Infinity, draggableLayers);


        if (hit)
        {
            holdDownTime += 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (hit && holdDownTime >= 0.5f)
        {
            Vector3 direction = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(direction);
            rb.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * 500f);
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        holdDownTime = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Physics2D.RayCastAll()` to get all the ray Hits , then check if the hit collider is equals your target object , if yes then do the rotation.

Comment: Doesn't the Physics2D.RaycastAll need PolygonCollider2D to hit them?

Comment: No. physics2D.RaycastAll casts a ray against Colliders in the Scene, returning all Colliders that contact with it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to this: on a separate GameObject, I detect the click and fill an empty static GameObject "container" on the physics 2D "hit". On the actual GameObject I want to rotate, I check to see if on GetMouseButton if the object is = to the static container object. Then allow the rotation. Works perfectly.